# Addition of 2-digit numbers using stack

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
model small
.stack 50
.data

msg db 10,13,"data is stored in  $"
msg1 db 10,13,"enter second number $"
num1 dw ?
num2 dw ?

.code
.startup

mov bl,0
mov ah,09
lea dx,msg
int 21h 
mov bx,0

read :
mov ah,01h       
;input number
int 21h    
cmp al,13      

je second       
mov cl,al
mov ch,0
sub cl,48    
converts ascii value
mov ax,10     

mul bx        

mov bx,ax 
add bx,cx
jmp read

second:
mov num1,bx
mov bx,0
mov ah,09h
mov dx,offset msg1
int 21h

read1:
mov ah,01h
int 21h
cmp al,13
je aedd
mov cl,al
mov ch,0
sub cl,48
mov ax,10
mul bx
add bx,cx

jmp read1

aedd:
add bx,num1

push '@'             

disp:


mov dx,ax
mov ax,bx
mov bx,dx
div bx
cmp ah,0
je poppy
push ax
jmp disp

poppy:

pop dx
cmp dx,'@'
je exit
mov ah,02h
int 21h

exit:
mov ah,04ch
mov al,0
int 21h
end
```

`cmp al,13` is used to check whether the char is number or enter key.
Initially `bx` is 0.
`push '@'` is used to check end of stack.

I have taken single digit numbers and converted them to their place values. Then I have done their addition, put them on the stack and tried to display them. In some pc, it shows "divide overflow".

I don't know where I am wrong! Please help me with the logic.

Comment: It should do divide overflow, that's how `DIV r16` is defined. Check instruction reference guide. (for example you can start with some HTML variant, if you don't like full Intel's docs: http://x86.renejeschke.de/ )

Answer (score 2):

### Problems

> ```
> mov ax,10
> mul bx
> add bx,cx
>
> jmp read1
> ```

When you get the second number you forget to actually put the product back in `BX`. You did this correctly when calculating the first number though.

```
mov ax,10
mul bx
mov bx,ax     <<<<<< Add this line
add bx,cx
jmp read1
```

---

> ```
> disp:
>
> mov dx,ax
> mov ax,bx
> mov bx,dx
> div bx
> cmp ah,0
> je poppy
> push ax
> jmp disp
> ```

Here's a lot amiss:

- You seem to be thinking that `AX` will hold 10 at the start of this snippet, but it will have the value 010Dh at this point!
- A **word sized** division uses `DX:AX` as dividend. Since your number is just 1 word, you need to put it in `AX` **and zero the high part in `DX`**.
- When you perform a **word sized** division the quotient will be in `AX`. Then you shouldn't check the `AH` register!
- Since it's the remainder that needs to be pushed, it won't help writing `push ax`. Use `push dx`.
- ...

---

### Solution

You definitely should take a look at this recent post
[Displaying numbers with DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904075/displaying-numbers-with-dos/45904076#45904076).

You'll find there a perfect explanation of what you need to do.
It even uses the same technique of pushing some value on the stack to know where the number ends.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear the dx register before division that is why its causing division overflow.

```
 disp:       
       mov dx,ax
       mov ax,bx
       mov bx,dx
       mov dx, 0    <---- this has to be added 
       div bx
       cmp ah,0
       je poppy
        push ax
jmp disp
```